# Confused by output of cat /proc/stat

Tags: centos

I'm on a university server running Centos 6.10. I'm trying to calculate the amount of time that the system has been in idle task. Im looking at the /proc/stat pseudo file. According to the man page the 4th column in the 1st row is supposed to be the amount of time the system has spent idle in 100ths of a second.

The issue I'm having is that this value is extremely large. When I divide it by 100 to get the seconds, and then divide that result by 60^2*24 (number of seconds in a day) to get the number of days, the resulting answer is longer than the uptime of the system.

In a nutshell this value, the way that I'm calculating it, is telling me that the system has been in idle for longer than it's been up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the sum of the idle times on all cpus.

The first `cpu` line of `/proc/stat` is followed by `cpu0`, `cpu1` similar lines for each *online* cpu. This is documented in newer versions of the [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) manpage.

Notice that not all cpus may be online, but the idle value from the first/system entry (as its equivalent in seconds from the second field of `/proc/uptime`) is calculated for all the *possible* cpus [1].

So you can divide it by the number of cpus to get *something* like an average.

One way to get the number of present, possible, on and offline cpus, is to look at the files `/sys/devices/system/cpu/` directory.

---

[1] you can have a look at the [fs/proc/stat.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/stat.c?id=1064f874abc0d05eeed8993815f584d847b72486#n80) in the source:

```
static int show_stat(struct seq_file *p, void *v)
{
        ...
        for_each_possible_cpu(i) {
                ...
                idle += get_idle_time(kcs, i);
        ...
        seq_put_decimal_ull(p, "cpu  ", nsec_to_clock_t(user));
        ...
        seq_put_decimal_ull(p, " ", nsec_to_clock_t(idle));
        ...
        for_each_online_cpu(i) {
                ...
                seq_printf(p, "cpu%d", i);
                ...
                idle = get_idle_time(kcs, i);
                ...
                seq_put_decimal_ull(p, " ", nsec_to_clock_t(idle));
```

Comment: The exact number I'm getting for the idle time (4th column 1st row) is 908486250. It's a 4 core system, so dividing that by 4 gives 227121562.5, and finally dividing that by 100 to convert it from 100ths of seconds to seconds gives ~2271216. I would think this number should match the second number output by /proc/uptime, but it doesn't. That number is 512188.75.

Comment: there may have been fixes since rhel / centos 6. Also, the code from `stat.c` handles online cpus specially and does more checks than that from `uptime.c`. But _both_ will sum up the idle values for all _possible_ cpus (`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible`). Since the processors may be turned on and offline at will this is bound to be unreliable -- that's why I said its a "kind of" average.